# how to construct name on terraform v0.12

Tags: terraform

previously on v0.11 these works on my deployment

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "my_tg" {
name  = "${var.SCHOOL}-${var.DEPT}-${var.ID}-tg"
```

However on v0.12 I'm kinda lost how to adjust with thier update, I'm trying these however gives me error

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "my_tg" {
name  = "{"var.SCHOOL"}-{"var.DEPT"}-{"var.ID"}-tg"
```

ERROR

```
on alb-tg.tf line 2, in resource "aws_alb_target_group" "my_tg":
2:   name       = "{"var.SCHOOL"}-{"var.DEPT"}-{"var.ID"}-tg"
An argument definition must end with a newline.
```

Comment: Did you have an error using the original format as-used in 0.11 too? If so, what was that error?

Comment: James Thorpe -  my bad, thanks for your suggestion. I was kind of advanced to adjust :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terraform v0.12 the way you interpolate variables in a string did not change.

The example you provided is still valid.

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "my_tg" {
name  = "${var.SCHOOL}-${var.DEPT}-${var.ID}-tg"
```

The only change in v0.12 is when you are passing only a variable as the name. So the previous `name = ”${var.name}”` changed in `name = var.name`. But seeing that you are adding the dash between variables the first example you provided is a valid string and should work.